# MariaDB root user

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

Good day,

I logged into mariadb with the skip grant tables option. Then I set password for the localhost root user. Then I flushed the privileges. However, I can still log in with the following command.

```
mysql -uroot
```

This is my version of MariaDb.

Server version: 10.0.27-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you terminated the process that runs with `--skip-grant-tables`. Just in case, terminate all mysql/mariadb processes, restart the service and try again. As which user to you run `mysql -u root`?

Comment: Yes. When I query for the root record in the mysql.user table, the password column has a value, but I can still log in without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently running `mysql -uroot` under `root` system account.

`10.0.27-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` is a package provided by Ubuntu. Recently they switched to the [Unix socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/) for the local root account by default. If you run

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host, password, plugin from mysql.user;
```

you should see something like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host, password, plugin from mysql.user;
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| user | host      | password                                  | plugin      |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| root | localhost | *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29 | unix_socket |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Naturally, if you don't want it, you can remove `unix_socket` from the `plugin` field, flush privileges, then it should work as before.